# Esp32 Arduino SPIFFS Based Static Web Addresses Case Sensitive

Tags: esp32, platformio, spiffs

I am trying to make a static webserver on an ESP32 via PlatformIO. I am using the built in "Upload Filesystem" task in PlatformIO to upload a www folder. I then use `server.serveStatic("/", SPIFFS, "/www/");` to serve the pages. The issue is the url is case sensitive, and I need them to not be.

I assume this is due to the underlying SPIFFS filesystem, and to fix it I should somehow change that.

Comment: Not sure what you means 'case sensitive', I uses Arduino to upload data to SPIFFS (I actually can't make the upload to SPIFFS works on PlatformIO), and never have any issue.

Comment: 192.168.4.1/Control.html works, but 192.168.4.1/control.html does not. I know sometimes this is intended, anything beyond the first / can be case sensitive, but I would prefer it if it were not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the standard ESP32 webserver library you could do the following:
In your handler function compare the path argument you get with

webServer.uri()

which is a char array then use int strcasecmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
the function part would be

```
if (strcasecmp (webServer.uri(), "www/mysmallcapslink.html") == 0) {
... do your stuff here ...
e.g. serve the file
}
```

Note == 0 means the two strings (C-strings with small s) are identic (apart from the case). So url requests like
www/Mysmallcapslink.html
www/MySmallCapsLink.html
would all be handled by the same handler.

Info about srtcasecmp:

> DESCRIPTION The strcasecmp() function shall compare, while ignoring differences in case, the string
>   pointed to by s1 to the string pointed to by s2. The strncasecmp() function shall
>   compare, while ignoring differences in case, not more than n bytes from the string
>   pointed to by s1 to the string pointed to by s2.
>
> strncasecmp() shall behave as if the strings had been converted to lowercase and then a
>   byte comparison performed.
>
> RETURN VALUE Upon completion, strcasecmp() shall return an integer greater than, equal to, or less
>   than 0, if the string pointed to by s1 is, ignoring case, greater than, equal to, or
>   less than the string pointed to by s2, respectively.